# How to set firebase creation timestamp using JsonSerializable in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, firebase

I'm using JsonSerializable and I want my firebase document to contain a creation timestamp. Here's an example of how I'm achieving this. It seems to be working though it will fail if I try to access the timestamp before the document is stored, which I'm not concerned about. Plus [this](https://stackoverflow.com) caveat.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'example.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
class Example {
  @JsonKey(
    name: 'created',
    fromJson: _fromJsonTimestamp,
    toJson: _toJsonTimestamp,
    includeFromJson: true,
    includeToJson: true,
  )
  DateTime? _created;
  final String someId;

  Example({required this.someId});

  factory Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ExampleFromJson(json);

  // Assume non-null since value is set by server when document is persisted
  DateTime get created => _created!;

  // Set the first time this is persisted
  static dynamic _toJsonTimestamp(DateTime? time) =>
      time == null ? FieldValue.serverTimestamp() : Timestamp.fromDate(time);

  static DateTime _fromJsonTimestamp(Timestamp? ts) =>
      ts != null ? ts.toDate() : DateTime(1900);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleToJson(this);
}
```

I was originally writing the timestamp in the code that saves the firebase document, but that seems to miss the point of using JsonSerializable. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a simpler or more idiomatic way to get a server generated timestamp. Thanks!